# OTRS + REST + List available queues

Tags: rest, otrs

there is any way to list the available queues in OTRS by REST? for example, when i insert a new Tiket i put QueueID with the Queue Id, it is possible to get the queues by REST ?

this is my request:

```
{
   "UserLogin":"web.service",
   "Password":"*****",
   "TicketID":"1161",
   "Ticket":{
      "StateID":65,
      "QueueID":62
   },
   "DynamicField":[
      {
         "Name":"PMSupFluxo",
         "Value":"Nec_Desenv"
      },
      {
         "Name":"FormClassificacaoDsv",
         "Value":2
      }
   ],
   "Article":{
      "ArticleTypeID":10,
      "SenderTypeID":1,
      "From":"Web Service <user@email.com.br>",
      "Subject":"Encaminhado Desenvolvimento Sprint",
      "Body":"Encaminhar para Sprint: Andamento criado em: 01/08/2016 16:56:40",
      "ContentType":"text/plain; charset=utf8",
      "MimeType":"text/plain",
      "Charset":"UTF8",
      "QueueID":62
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `Queue` instead of `QueueID`. And, no, unfortunately it is not possible to retrieve a list of Queues using web services.